# JPA delete method returns 200 but doesn't delete

Tags: java, typescript, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using Postman to test my JPA delete method and when I test it, it returns a 200 response, but does not actually delete from my DB.

Repo -

```
@Repository
public interface TeamUserRepository extends JpaRepository<TeamUser, Long> {
    void deleteByUserId(Integer userId);
}
```

Service -

```
public void removeTeamUser(Integer userId) {
    teamUserRepository.deleteByUserId(userId);
}
```

Controller -

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{teamId}/users/{userId}")
public void removeUserFromTeam(Integer userId) {
    teamService.removeTeamUser(userId);
}
```

Typescript -

```
export const removeUserFromTeam = (teamId: number | string, userId: number | string) =>
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/team/${teamId}/users/${userId}`)
```

Comment: Please also post  your entity class.
If in your entity class had u been defined ```id``` instead of ```userId```. then you no need to even write method in repository class. In service class you can call directly call
```teamUserRepository.deleteById(userId);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `userId` must be null. That's why there is no delete.

You need to bind the *Path Parameters* to the method parameters.

So, in the `Controller`, change

```java
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{teamId}/users/{userId}")
public void removeUserFromTeam(Integer userId) {
    teamService.removeTeamUser(userId);
}
```

to

```java
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{teamId}/users/{userId}")
public void removeUserFromTeam(@PathVariable("teamId") Integer teamId, @PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) {
    teamService.removeTeamUser(userId);
}
```

Comment: That was it, can't believe I missed that! Thanks